# Cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later

Tags: linux, passwd

With several commands in Linux, I get the error:

```
cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?  Also I don't get in my /etc/shadow directory.

Comment: you have to raise your user level by using "sudo" or "su" command.

Comment: Your /etc/shadow _directory_?!?  /etc/shadow should be a file.  Please give the exact command you're trying to execute.

Comment: In my case root filesystem was full :-p

Answer (score 26):

If no `.lock` files are present but you still cannot create a user try the following

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

If logged in as `root` then use

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Comment: This solved the issue I had after booting into recovery mode by editing the grub entry

Comment: but where shall one look for the `.lock` files? thanks to @trevorRobinson it seems one should look in `/etc/`, correct?

Comment: What if it says `mount: cannot remount /dev/dm-0 read-write, is write-protected`. I'm in ChromeOS (Linux) with Dev Mode enabled.

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer??

Answer (score 16):

The user you are running the commands as lack the required privileges. Change to `root` user by issuing the command

```
su -
```

or if you have/use `sudo`

```
sudo <command to run>
```

Answer (score 16):

If you have `-R /some/chroot` added to your `useradd` command, that might be the problem.

I thought it meant that the user would be jailed upon login, but that's not the case. By looking at strace output, I saw useradd chrooted into the specified directory, after which of course it cannot find /etc/passwd anymore. So I'm not sure what the option is for, but there's your (well, my) problem.

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying. After removing the `-R [dir]` option I was able to create the user.

Comment: Nice guess! Thank you. I also understood that the chroot for `useradd` is not what you think it is :) It only uses the specified dir as a root for the user's *system*. It's useful for cloned isolated sub-OS, which is rarely what you want...

Answer (score 10):

That's because you don't have permissions for those operations

- You can't read `/etc/shadow`
- You can't directly modify `/etc/passwd`

You can change both files through specialized commands (e.g you can change your password).

Comment: to change password, use " passwd <username> "

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this when a disk error occurred during a userdel operation and the system had to be rebooted. I needed to delete all four of the following files to proceed:

```
sudo rm /etc/passwd.lock
sudo rm /etc/shadow.lock
sudo rm /etc/group.lock
sudo rm /etc/gshadow.lock
```

Answer (score 7):

This can also be caused by running out of space on the root filesystem. Use `strace` to be sure. `strace` is your friend.

Comment: I've been reading many threads with my problem and that was actually the solution. Should be one of the first things to check when having any filesystem problems, I guess. I'm using `df` instead of `strace` though. How would `strace` help me? Never used it

Comment: Well, if you already guessed that the problem might be running out of space, then df can help. But strace will tell you what the error code was when it tried to lock the file, so it should remove the guesswork. The way I usually call strace is `strace -f -e trace=file ` *command* since this usually gives the most useful results.

Answer (score 3):

**A demo of this error on Ubuntu 14.04:**

```
user@mybox:/home$ sudo useradd eric
user@mybox:/home$ userdel eric
userdel: Permission denied.
userdel: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

sudo gives you the permission to lock it.

```
user@mybox:/home$ sudo userdel eric
user@mybox:/home$
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for /etc/group.lock, /etc/passwd.lock and /etc/shadow.lock files and remove them.

Be careful to only remove the files ending in 'lock' or else you might damage your system.

Reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/523896

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, since /etc was full.
This is why /etc/passwd could not be written.
Make sure that you have enough space on /etc, if not then enlarge it or clean unnecessary stuff.