# adduser: cannot lock /etc/gshadow;

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, centos

With running serval commands in Linux, I am getting  the error when trying to create a new user:

```
 sh-4.2$ sudo adduser mbyousaf
adduser: /etc/gshadow.1270: Structure needs cleaning
adduser: cannot lock /etc/gshadow; try again later.
```

Does anybody know how to solve it? I am using my sudo command to add the user

Comment: Not seen that before, the only links I found with google suggest disk corruption. Maybe boot from recovery media and check the disk partition?

Comment: Have you seen it: https://superuser.com/questions/296373/cannot-lock-etc-passwd-try-again-later?